# How to cycle through all the players and then begin again?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a function called NewTurn() that sets up the next player. Currently I'm using an if-else to change the players:

```
if (p == players[0]) 
{ 
    p = players[1]; 
}
else 
{ 
    p = players[0]; 
}
```

What if I want 3 players? Isn't there any easier way to write this with the %.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One simple solution is to have a `playerCounter` that just keeps incrementing each time you request the next player. Then you choose the player using `playerCounter % players.Length`. This will work for any number of players in the `players` array.

For example:

```
private static int playerCounter = 0;
private static string[] players = { "John", "Mary", "Randy", "Martha" };

private static string GetNextPlayer()
{
    return players[playerCounter++ % players.Length];
}

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while (true)
    {
        var player = GetNextPlayer();
        Console.WriteLine($"Current player is: {player}");
        Console.Write("Press any key to move to the next player...");
        Console.ReadKey();
        Console.WriteLine('\n');
    }
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: p = players[pCount++ % players.Length]; // It works!

Comment: @RufusL I never thougt of this before, that usage of modulo is genious! ^^ It even solves the issue with Lists that have dynamic length